# Como deixar o Scroll de uma página suave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Como fazer para que o Scroll (barra de rolagem) de uma página fique suave? E se puderem, como personalizá-la.

Exemplo: http://themenectar.com/demo/salient/blog/

Comment: Recentemente usei num projeto um plugin chamado jScrollbar. Bem simples que personaliza a barra de rolagem e também pode tornar a mesma mais suave.

Comment: [Central de ajuda: Por que as pessoas podem editar minhas publicações? Como funciona a edição?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: Olá, @Alexandre. Olhei as suas questões, e aparentemente todas as edições estão corretas. De qualquer forma, se algo foi realmente editado indevidamente, você tem a opção de reverter, no link "editar". Caso queira, participe no http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com para discutir o assunto. De qualquer forma, visite o Meta para ter uma visão geral sobre o site e contribuir com sua opinião.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Essa página que referiu usa um [plugin do jQuery chamado NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/).

Ele é bem fácil de implementar, só precisa de colocar este código dentro da sua tag `<head>`.

#### #1 - carregar a biblioteca do jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### #2 - carregar a biblioteca do NiceScroll

```
<script src="http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
```

#### #3 - ativar o plugin na página

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("html").niceScroll();
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/aB8GK/)

#### Outros plugins:

- https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll
- https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll
- http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio novamente me ajudando! :D