# Click no link que leva para uma outra parte da mesma pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Estou criando uma pagina web que os links do menu irão levar para parte de baixo do texto e  gostaria de usar um efeito para deslizar do ponto A para o B devagar. Como faço isso?
Ex: Quando click no menu ( ir para footer ) Descer para o footer devagar...

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer isso com JavaScript nativo tens de ter em consideração algumas coisas que explico em baixo. Se queres/podes fazer isso com jQuery podes [ver esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14682/129).

Fazendo com JavaScript simples e HTML os passos são:

#1 - criar links internos.

Usa `href="#idDoElement"` e depois um elemento com essa ID. Assim quando clicares na ancora a página muda o scroll para mostrar esse elemento.

Exemplo:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #dff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#elemento10">Clica aqui para fazer scroll para o numero 10</a>
</p>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div id="elemento10">10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
```

#2 agora fazer a mesma coisa mas com scroll suave.

O que precisas de fazer é, por ordem:

- captar o ID desejado
- parar o clique
- saber a posição do elemento desejado
- fazer scroll suave até lá

E isso pode ser feito assim com JavaScript nativo:

```js
var ancoras = document.querySelectorAll('a');
Array.from(ancoras).forEach(function(a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', scroll);
});

function animarScroll(atual, destino) {
  if (atual >= destino) return;
  document.body.scrollTop = atual;
  setTimeout(function() {
    animarScroll(atual += 50, destino);
  }, 50);
}

function scroll(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = this.getAttribute('href');
  var el = document.querySelector(id);
  var posicao = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  animarScroll(this.scrollTop, posicao);
}
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #dff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#elemento10">Clica aqui para fazer scroll para o numero 10</a>
</p>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div id="elemento10">10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
```

Há maneiras mais interessantes de animar esse scroll, neste exemplo ficou um scroll suave linear, como exemplo.