# Como pegar a posição de um id com jquery para atribuir um efeito ao rolar o scroll?

Tags: jquery

Quero fazer esses efeitos muito comuns em sites que quando rola o scroll ate um certo id ou classe ele faz um efeito, eu não sei como ele sabe que chegou em tal parte da pagina, alguém me dá uma luz?

Comment: Ou se preferires, com jQuery: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14682/129

Comment: Não é isso, não é scroll suave que quero

Comment: Ok, podes [edit] a pergunta e clarificar? Na pergunta que marquei como duplicada mostro exatamente como pegar a posição de um ID e como comparar com o scroll.

Comment: Será isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4126/129 ?