# Redirecionar para outra parte da mesma pagina php

Tags: php, html

Quero fazer um site one page, mas não sei exatamente como fazer.
Como no exemplo: http://www.lucianocandido.com.br/
Quem puder me ajudar agradeço!

Comment: Você pode estudar Smooth Scrolling, esse padrão irá te ajudar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como deixar o Scroll de uma página suave?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14644/como-deixar-o-scroll-de-uma-p%c3%a1gina-suave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa de uma âncora.

No link que deseja que seja clicado faça assim:

```
<a class="qualquer_class" href="#Form-Interesse"></a>
```

Já a div que deseja que apareça quando clicar, faça assim:

```
<div class="qualquer_class" id="Form-Interesse"></div>
```